# How to update a text label from a usercontrol on the same form

Tags: vb.net, forms

Using VB.NET Windowsforms, I need to update a label on 'form1' from 'usercontrol' displayed  within form1.

The usercontrol is added to the form using:

```
            Dim userControl As New Settings_SQLite_Gen_UserControl
            Me.Settings_Panel.Controls.Add(userControl)
            userControl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
```

I've tried On form1:

```
Private Delegate Sub UpdateLabelDel(ByVal txt As String)

Public Sub UpdateLabel(ByVal txt As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(New UpdateLabelDel(AddressOf UpdateLabel), txt)
    Else
        Label1.Text = txt
    End If
End Sub
```

And in the usercontrol:

```
 Private Sub Reset_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Reset_btn.Click
Dim SomeText As String = "Some text to change the label to"
UpdateLabel(SomeText)
End Sub
```

I placed a breakpoint in the 'Sub UpdateLabel' and it does get called, however the label is not updated.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You should see the Docs about [Invoke/BeginInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) and how they work. + How does the UseControl know about a delegate (even though it's using the method) in another class? Also, are there any cross-thread calls, here?

Comment: Thanks Jimi, after reading the link I got a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks Jimi, after reading the link I got a better understanding. I added a ref too form1 from form2: ' Private otherForm As form1' and amended 'Public Sub New(Inst As form1)', ' otherForm = Inst'. Then simply called 'otherForm.label1.Text = SomeText' in the click event. Then it worked. Many thanks Andy :-)

Comment: Sorry I also amended how the usercontrol was added to the form  ' Dim userControl As New Settings_Warnings_UserControl(Me)'.